# Librerias en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema al querer iniciar un proyecto desde otra computadora. Y las dos PC's tenemos la misma version de **ANDROID 2.2 RC** por las dudas, pero solo me ocurre con mi pc, pruebe en otra y sin problemas. Y tengo la misma version.

```
Error: failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3
       *Intall Build Tools 23.0.3 and sync project*
```

Instale como tal y pide la revision **23.0.3** hizo el sync, pero volvio a parecer el mismo error, volvi hacer lo que me pedia y se soluciono, pero al dar **sync and project** o recargar el gradle. Salio uno nuevo

```
Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.alirezaaa:FilePickerLibrary:3.5.1
*Show in file*
*Show in Project Structure dialog*
```

**Ahora les dejo mi gradle tal y como esta, y solo en una pc no hay revision y vuelvo a decir que todas tenemos la misma** Version 2.2 RC

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Dependecies**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se a que se debe, ya que pongo bien la libreria y la importación está bien. Lo hago tal y como dice aquí.
[Enlace al repositorio](http://github.com/DeveloperPaul123/FilePickerLibrary)

Comment: Suena como que la libreria no esta en tus repos de Maven/gradle , probablemente esta faltando, pero como lo tenes en el cache local en la primera PC lo resuelve igual. Podrías confirmar si un proyecto nuevo resuelve esa dependencia?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba poner

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

en el archivo build.gradle del proyecto (no del modulo)

Comment: Pues eso si tengo en el projecto. Gracias por tratar de ayudar